# Direct proof for closure of a set $E$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a metric space and $E\subset X $ be a subset of $X$.   Let $cl(E)=E\cup E'$, where $E'=$ set of all limit points of $E$.

**Claim:** $cl (E)$ is closed. 
If $E$ is finite, then E has no limit points and therefore $cl (E)= E$ and since E contains all its limit points (which are none) so vacuously $E$ is closed.
So let $E$ be infinite.

**Proof:** Let $x\in X$ be a limit point of $cl (E)$. Then given any $\delta\gt 0, B_X(x,\delta)\cap cl (E)$ is infinite.  It follows that either $B_X(x,\delta)\cap E$ or $B_X(x,\delta)\cap E'$ is infinite. This implies that either $x\in E'$ or $x\in (E')'$. **(?)** 
Since, $E'$ is a closed set, it follows that $(E')'\subset E'$ and therefore $x\in E'$ or $x\in (E')'\implies x\in E'\subset cl(E)$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, it is proven that $cl(E)$ is closed.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

**Edit:** Closed set definition being used here: $A\subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space, is said to be closed if $A$ contains all its limit points.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks for the comment. I have added the case: If E is finite, then $cl (E)=E$ as there won't be any limit points of E so vacuously E is closed.

Comment: What definition of closed are you using?

Comment: @RobertShore: $E$ is closed in metric space $X$ if $E$ contains all its limit points.

Comment: How do you know that $(E')' \subseteq E'$?  In other words, how do you know that $E'$ is closed?  (It is, but how do you know that?)

Comment: @RobertShore: I have proved that already and taken it here as a lemma.

Comment: Okay.  As long as you've separately proved that, then your proof is correct.

Comment: @RobertShore: Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the finite & infinite cases together:

(1). For any $F\subset X$ we have $x\in F\cup F'$ iff every open set containing $x$ contains some member of $ F$ (which may or may not be equal to $x$).

(2). Let $x\in (E\cup E')'.$  Let $U$ be any  an open set containing $x$. By (1) with $F=(E\cup E')$, the set $U$ contains some $y\in (E\cup E')$. It does not matter whether or not $y=x$. What matters is that some $z\in E$ belongs to $U$ because

(i) if $y\in E,$ let $z=y,$ or

(ii) if $y\in E',$ then the open set $U,$ which contains $y,$  must contain some $z\in E.$

Hence by (i) & (ii) every open set $U$ containing $x$ must contain some $z\in E$. So $x\in (E\cup E')$ by (1) with $F=E$. So we have $$x\in (E\cup E')'\implies x\in (E\cup E').$$

Comment: The key in (2)(ii) is that the open set U containing x is also an open set containing y.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

Suppose $x \notin \operatorname{cl} E$, then $x \notin E$ and $x \notin E'$.

Then there must be a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that contains no point of $E$ (otherwise $x$ would be a limit point).

Furthermore, this holds for **every** element of $U$, hence $U$ does not intersect $\operatorname{cl} E$ and so we see that $(\operatorname{cl} E)^c$ is open from which we see that $\operatorname{cl} E$ is closed.

Comment: In this approach shouldn't this possibility also be considered: U may contain some element of E' hence U contains a limit point of E meaning that there exist proper subset $V\subset U$ such that $V\cap E$ is infinite immediately violating $U\cap E=$empty?

Comment: Suppose $y \in U \cap E'$. Then every neighbourhood of $y$ (including $U$) must have some element of $E$ which is a contradiction.